# download a generated image and send to email

Tags: php, image, email, download, gd

Salam

i generate a image by adding into it a text like this

```
function create_image() 
    {

        $im = imagecreatefrompng('coupon.png');

        $red = imagecolorallocate($im, 120, 20, 20);

        $font = 'font/arial.ttf';


        imagettftext($im, 36, 0, 176, 695, $red, $font, $_POST['Tdesc']);
        ob_start();
            imagepng($im);
            $image = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        echo '
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>

                    </title>
                </head>

                <body>
                    <form action="donwload.php" method="post">
                        <img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'" height="701" width="496" name="xx" />
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Genere le coupon</button>
                    </form>
                </body>
            </html>
        ';
}
```

i want to download this image by specify his name and extension and also send it to an addres email

Comment: tell the user to right-click/save-as the file. As you're doing it now, you're just embedding an image inside a form tag. it will NOT be submitted with the form, and will NOT be uploaded back to the server. Otherwise you're stuck REGENERATING the image on the server when the form's submitte, and at at that point, sending the email will be trivial

Comment: Check [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). As for what you have now, you will have a lot to do ...